# Is this bad coupling?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to solve a path planning problem in 3D space and have succeeded, but I don't know if my solution has adequately loose coupling. I have three source files, each containing a public class: Vertex.java, VertexHeuristicComparator.java and PathPlanningUtil.java.

Vertex contains three fields: A `Point` in 3D space (`location`), a reference to another vertex (`parent`) and a `float` holding the distance to the goal vertex (`distToGoal`). A collection of vertices is used in the path planning to explore the environment and find the best path.

VertexHeuristicComparator implements `Comparator<Vertex>`. I've overriden the compareTo method to use `distToGoal` and `parent` in the comparison. This method effectively defines what the best vertex is so that the path planning can prioritise the search.

PathPlanningUtil contains the method `planPath(Point start, Point goal)`. This method returns an `ArrayList<Vertex>` representing a path in 3D space from start to goal. This method uses a `VertexHeuristicComparator` to determine how the environment is explored by exploring the vertex which the VertexHeuristicComparator determines is the "lowest" vertex.

Since `VertexHeuristicComparator` is central to the path planning logic. Changing the VertexHeuristicComparator source code will result in `planPath` returning different paths. Is it bad coupling for changes to VertexHeuristicComparator to drastically change the output of `planPath`?

Comment: Is there some reason you couldn't use a [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) (if needed) to swap in a different `Comparator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your direct question,

> Is it bad coupling for changes to VertexHeuristicComparator to
>   drastically change the output of planPath?

No. It would only be bad (tight) coupling if changes to `VertexHeuristicComparator` caused changes to the `PathPlanningUtil` *code*. As long as you can change the code of one class without having to change the code of another, you've achieved reasonably loose coupling.

Answer (score 0):

My general understanding of coupling is that it's more about not depending on specific implementations instead of generic interfaces - for instance, explicitly returning or requiring an ArrayList instead of a List, or hard-coding the use of a particular thing to far down in the logic chain.

What I might suggest for your particular example is having your path-planning accept as a parameter the heuristic to use (as a comparator). This would prevent your implementation of path-planning from depending specifically on the class you wrote for the comparator and allow the client (your main program, in this case) to provide the comparison strategy it wants to use as a heuristic.

So, to sum this up in a code example, I'd make the path planning method have a signature similar to:

`List<Vertex> planPath(Point start, Point goal, Comparator<Vertex> heuristic)`

and have the method calling plan path be the one that references your VertexHeuristicComparator class, using it as the heuristic argument.